# Regex bash script

Tags: regex, linux

Can anyone help me understand why this doesn't work? Just trying out some simple regex in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

re="-regex_"

if [[ "$re" =~ ^[-[:alpha:]_]+$ ]]; then
        echo "Regex"

else
        echo "this is not regex"        
fi
```

Cheers

Comment: On mine it does nothing, no error or anything.

Comment: What is your BASH version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are hoping that the "-regex_" will evaluate to true in your if statement.

on the [:alpha:] tag there is nothing to say search for more than one alpha-numeric character.

try

```
[[ "$re" =~ ^-[[:alpha:]]+_$ ]]
```

Comment: I've followed you're example and still nothing. I have the permissions set and I'm in the right folder.

Comment: did you use the edited one? the first one i posted had a mistake in it... love regexes -_-

Comment: I just tried it and still nothing, very strange. Any ideas?

Comment: You are having an issue with running bash and not just regex.  The comments are right that your original solution should return Regex, my solution has more to do with matching data which starts with - and ends with _.  Try looking at your BASH version and see if the syntax you are using is valid.  When you run the script it returns "this is not regex" right?

Comment: It returns nothing, no error or anything, just moves onto the next line as if nothing happened. BASH version 4.1.2

Comment: what happens if you echo something out before doing anything else in the script?

Comment: I've added an echo at the start and nothing. I've also tested another bash script that does just that and it echos out to the screen as it should.

Comment: Ok so something is different between those two files.  Some things to check between the files: permissions on the file, and the interpreter at the beginning of your script (the #!/bin/bash). Apart from that, figuring out why this script doesn't run and the other does is more something you are going to have to figure out.

Comment: I think I've figured it out but I almost don't want to say what was wrong. I called the file test and I think this is conflicting with an actual command already in use. I get output now.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are having an error running it, make sure you are using unix line endings (run it through dos2unix) and make sure it is marked executable.  Otherwise, the script prints "Regex" for me.